# Why putting OR with three boolean type columns would randomly fetch or sometimes not fetch the data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table

```
Students
```

now students has 3 `Booleans` checks

```
1. IsRecordArchived
2. IsActive
3. IsOnProbation
```

The `Booleans` are not relevant to each other and doesn't depend on each other but the record should not appear or included in the result set if any of it is `TRUE`.

e.g.

A `student` can be I`sRecordArchived = TRUE` but might not be the other two i.e. `IsActive= false` and `IsOnProbation = false` or could be `IsActive= True` and `IsOnProbation= false` or `true` even.

Or it could all be equal to `TRUE`. Could be anything but ultimately it should not be included in the record.

Now, my query

```
var students= db.Students.where(s=> !IsActive || !IsRecordArchived || !IsOnProbation).ToList();
```

Would sometimes work but sometimes not. How do I adjust these?

e.g.

studnet records

```
ID  Name  IsArchived  IsDeleted IsOnProbation
1   Tom       1          0           0
2   Dick      1          1           0
3   Harry     0          0           1
4.  Amas      0          0           0
```

Now, according to my query; only `4. Amas` should be in the result set not the others.

Comment: @Selvin: I wish I could do that but we are using the provided dlls and it's already made; legacy you could say so unfortunately have to do in this.

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking for ... your query always works ... but you don't understand what it does ... it takes all records which: are not active or are not archived or are on probation)... Please show what data "doesn't work"

Comment: @Selvin: i will explain; see.. the record shouldn't be fetch if any of the boolean is = TRUE

Comment: Then obviously it's no OR

Comment: `only 4. Amas should be in the result set not the others.` no. All rows except `Dick` match that condition. Harry and Amas aren't archived, and Tom isn't deleted. OR means that at least *one* of the conditions should hold.

Comment: Review the [Boolean logical operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators) and how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the record should not appear or included in the result set if any of it is TRUE.

Does this really implement that logic?

```cs
var students= db.Students.where(s=> !IsActive || !IsRecordArchived || IsOnProbation).ToList();
```

That's going to get records where either of `IsActive` and `IsRecordArchived`  is `false` or `IsOnProbation` is `true`.

If you want records where none are `true`, i.e. all are `false`, then you need to specify that all are `false` and use `AND` operators:

```cs
var students= db.Students.Where(s=> !IsActive && !IsRecordArchived && !IsOnProbation).ToList();
```

Comment: @Selvin, that's what they put in their code but their description of the desired functionality says otherwise, so I think that's a mistake in the code. If it's not then they have provided an inaccurate description of the problem.